# Proxy detection - to protect fraudsters who bypass geolocation controls using proxy

Tags: asp.net, security, proxy, dns, ip

Say, a merchant have an asp.net with c# e-commerce website abc.com, he would like to allow **Spanish** customers only. But a credit card fraudster located in **Greek** attempts to purchase goods online with a stolen credit card having a **Span** billing address. System try to protect the fraud by matching up customer IP location and billing address but  the fraudster can bypass this check by selecting a proxy located in **Span**.

So, is this possible to block the proxy user? I do not want any third party paid proxy detector.

I have following discussion regarding proxy, but non of them is match enough with me.
[Proxy detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487566/proxy-detection), 
[.NET proxy detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434285/net-proxy-detection) and http://www.maxmind.com/app/proxy (paid service)

As I guess, we may able to detect proxy customer by knowing what DNS he is using in his machine. Normally, customer should use the DNS of ISP of IP. If customer is using another public DNS, can we treat him as a proxy user?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: If the proxy is good, then no, you don't have a chance. Random blocking using reverse DNS is sure to also block legitimate users.

Comment: I concur. This is partly why a lot of merchants will only ship to the billing address, at least for new customers.

Comment: Blocking by DNS server (even if tracking what DNS server was used were possible) would lead to shooting lots of legitimate clients who use DNS of Comodo or of Google or other services.

Comment: @JamesAylett, Some merchant sell digital products due to instant delivery say Product key, Xbox card,  ringtune etc

Comment: I would advise against filtering out public DNS users. Many people use a public DNS (e.g. Google DNS) because their ISP's DNS are flaky or take too long to refresh their cache. This would block out legitimate users that happen to use a public DNS.

Answer (score 0):

If flash is a viable option you should be able to detect the users real ip that way.

Comment: Nope, this will only block out the dumbest of fraudsters. Easiest way to work around this is to just disable flash.

Comment: We can have real IP from server side using C# too. Proxy user also have real ip. so, how does it help us